# Node.js HTTPS jquery not working

Tags: node.js, https

When my NodeJS server was running with HTTP, any client-side jQuery script from google's API worked well. But I changed all requests to HTTPS with a self-signed certificate, and after that my static CSS files still work, but Jquery doesn't. Is there a reason why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.

The API scripts google Distributes comes in both http and https links. I found out that to use these scripts, you have to also access these external scripts through HTTPS.